# If $E$ is infinite and countable.....

Tags: elementary-set-theory

One of my friends gave me the following problem which was as follows:

> If $E$ is infinite and countable and $$E=\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} E_i$$then which of the following is/are correct?
>
> 1. at least one $E_i$ is infinite
> 2. infinite number of  $E_i$'s are infinite,
> 3. no $E_i$ need be infinite
> 4. if $E_i$'s are pairwise disjoint ,then at least one $E_i$ is infinite.

I think option (2) can be ruled out even though I can not prove it. I am not sure about option 1,3 and 4. Can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**: Can you make the natural numbers into a countable union of finite, disjoint sets?

Comment: Yes. I think I can make it. Using what @Asaf told ,we can write $\Bbb N=\{1\} \cup \{2\} \cup \{3\} \cup....$ which is a countable union of finite disjoint set. Using it, option (3) looks correct. Am I right?

Comment: Precisely! Nice work. (And in fact this shows that *only* that option is correct.)

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** Write $\Bbb N$ as a union of singletons.

Comment: Skunked by three seconds! Curses! ;-)

Comment: @Cameron: Yeah, although it would have been more impressive if my answer was longer... :-)

Comment: +1 to both you and @Cameron. And I was going to answer but edited first ... :-(

Comment: @amWhy: Aww.... :-)